# Create a barrier for each time c++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, thread-safety

How can organize a below program so that it will work as follows:
For each time each thread must wait as long as all other threads has not reached that time.  At the point when for the given time  all threads  are "executed"  the result value should be printed out.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

const int numThreads = 4;

typedef double Time;
double resultForGivenTime = 0;

class Printer
{
public:
    void print(Time time, double result)
    {
        mtx.lock();
        std::cout << "Time:"  << time << " -> Result:" << result << std::endl;
        resultForGivenTime = 0;
        mtx.unlock();
    }

private:
    std::mutex mtx;
};

Printer p;

void doIt (Printer& p, Time& t, int& id)
{
    //Is it possible to create here a barier so that
    //program output will look like this:
    //Time: 0 -> Result 6             # one or four time
    //Time: 1 -> Result 6            
    //Time: 2 -> Result 6
    //Time: 3 -> Result 6
    //Time: 4 -> Result 6
    resultForGivenTime += id;
    p.print(t, resultForGivenTime);
}

void handler(int id)
{
    for (Time time = 0.0; time < 5.0; ++time)
    {
        doIt(p, time, id);
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread threads[numThreads];

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; ++i)
        threads[i] = std::thread(handler, i);

     for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you do not want to use the Boost, a Barrier class can be developed using std::mutex and condition_variable.

Here is a simple Barrier class and its demo program.

### Barrier.h file:

```
#pragma once

#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

class Barrier
{
private:
    std::mutex m_mtx;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    unsigned m_count;

public:
    /// <summary>Ctor. Initializes a Barrier with count.</summary>
    explicit Barrier(const unsigned initialCount);

    /// <summary>
    /// Block the calling thread until the internal count reaches the value zero. Then all waiting threads are unblocked.
    /// </summary>
    void Wait();
};
```

### Barrier.cpp file:

```
#include "Barrier.h"

using namespace std;

Barrier::Barrier(const unsigned initialCount)
    : m_count(initialCount)
{ }

void Barrier::Wait()
{
    unique_lock<mutex> mtxLock(m_mtx);      // Must use unique_lock with condition variable.
    --m_count;
    if (0 == m_count)
    {
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }
    else
    {
        m_cv.wait(mtxLock, [this]{ return 0 == m_count; });      // Blocking till count is zero.
    }
}
```

### Demo code for Barrier class and sample output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include "barrier.h"

const int TotalThreads = 5;

static Barrier barrier(TotalThreads);

static void RunAtSameTime(int index)
{
    barrier.Wait();   // Comment this line out for Without barrier test.
    std::cout << index << " run at " << std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::thread threads[TotalThreads];
    std::cout << "Start all threads.\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < TotalThreads; ++i)
    {
        threads[i] = std::thread(RunAtSameTime, i);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    for (auto & th : threads) th.join();
}
/*
Sample output Without barrier:
    Start all threads.
    0 run at 14261019965559098
    1 run at 14261019975562801
    2 run at 14261019985570166
    3 run at 14261019995575084
    4 run at 14261020005577839

Sample output With barrier:
    Start all threads.
    3 run at 14261019189733066
    4 run at 14261019189733066
    1 run at 14261019189733066
    2 run at 14261019189733066
    0 run at 14261019189733066
*/
```

Comment: I am trying to run this code but getting the following error : `/tmp/ccfRwhVl.o:new_top.cpp:(.text+0x19): undefined reference to `Barrier::Wait()'`

Comment: @Tushar The Barrier.cpp file needs to be compiled and linked with the main  cpp file.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a combination of condition variables and a counter.  You can find a good example of usage here:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/condition_variable/condition_variable/

Alternatively, if you have Boost libraries available, you can use the [barrier](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers.barrier) class, which provides a nice wrapper:

```
#include <boost/thread/barrier.hpp>

class barrier
{
public:
    barrier(barrier const&) = delete;
    barrier& operator=(barrier const&) = delete;

    barrier(unsigned int count);
    template <typename F>
    barrier(unsigned int count, F&&);

    ~barrier();

    bool wait();
    void count_down_and_wait();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Granted this is just a simple example, so this wouldn't work quite as easily for larger examples... but in this case, it might just be easier to move the for loop from the handler into an omp parallel region in your main function. You can use the omp_get_thread_num() to set the id for each parallel occurance, and use `#pragma omp barrier` to get the desired barrier for output.

At least it should be simpler than using boost or creating your own barrier file.